# How do I get json data with fetch from my express server?

Tags: node.js, json, express, fetch-api

I’ve been trying to use fetch to get JSON data from my express server. However, it doesn’t work. I’ve tested the fetch function with [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) so I think my express code is the problem.

Here is my fetch code:

```
fetch("https://myexpressserver.com/api/example")
    .then(response=> {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data=> {
        console.log(data.text);
    })
```

And here is my express code:

```
app.get('/api/example', function(req, res){
    res.json({ text: 'This is what you should get if this works' });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `res.json` use `res.send`!

```
app.get('/api/example', function(req, res){
    res.send({ text: 'This is what you should get if this works' });
});
```

I also recommend to handle exception and don't use `return` as it will only cause error in the fetch request:

```
fetch("https://myexpressserver.com/api/example")
    .then(response=> {
        response.json();
    })
    .then(data=> {
        console.log(data.text);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
         console.error(err);
    })
```

Comment: Multiple issues here.
`response.json()` returns a promise. Right now, your first `then` does not return anything for the next `then`. If you remove the curly braces it works.
`res.send()` does convert the object to json, but maybe there is other middleware, so they do not want to call `send` yet.

Answer (score -1):

```html
const RequestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    };
fetch("https://myexpressserver.com/api/example",RequestOptions).then(Response=> Response.json()).then((data)=>{
           console.log(data.txt)
            })
```

try this because RequestOptions is important it tell what type of request we send to server

Comment: Why? GET is the default and `Content-Type` is irrelevant with GET.